# Format Pendrive using NTFS file system in Terminal(mac)

Tags: macos, terminal, filesystems

How to format pendrive using `diskutil` command by terminal? or Is any other way to format pendrive?

```
sudo reformat device
```

After get into correct volume, then try above command, but didn't work, still in FAT(32), I want to be in NTFS file system Please help me..

**Ref:** [Mac Commands.](http://mac.commands.com/diskutil/)

Answer (score 0):

I am using Tuxera NTFS app to able to format driver with NTFS though disk utility GUI.

http://www.tuxera.com/products/tuxera-ntfs-for-mac/